# Area of parametrized curve

Tags: integration, line-integrals, greens-theorem

A simple closed curve $C$ is given by $\textbf{x} = (f(t), tf(t)), t\in [a,b]$.

Show that the area enclosed by the curve is given by $A = \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}f(t)^2dt$.

I tried to use Green's theorem here, so choosing $\mathbf{F} = (0, -x)$ implies that the area is given by $$\int_{C}^{} \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{dx} = \int_a^b -f(t)\ (\frac{d}{dt}tf(t))\ dt = \int_a^b -f(t)(f(t) + tf'(t))\ dt = \int_a^b -f(t)^2 - tf(t)f'(t)\ dt$$

Then integration by parts gives me that $$\int_a^b tf(t)f'(t) = \frac{1}{2}(tf(t)^2 - \int_a^b f(t)^2\ dt)$$ and this result into the original yields

$$ \int_C \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{dx} = -\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b f(t)^2\ dt + tf(t)^2$$

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong or if this is the right approach to showing this result. How would I move forward here?

Comment: Since it is a closed curve you know that $f(a) = f(b)$  so what doe that mean for $t(f(t))^2|_a^b$

Comment: Clearly I forgot how IBP works. Thanks. Should I be getting a negative area?

Comment: If you go around the contour one way, you get a positive number and the other you will get a negative number.  But, the area should be positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F = (M, N)$, then, by greens theorem, if $\partial \Sigma$ is piecewise smooth :
$$
\oint_{\partial \Sigma} \textbf{F} .d\textbf{r} = \iint_{\Sigma}\frac{\partial N}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial y} dA
$$
We are given that $\partial \Sigma$ is described by $\textbf{r} = (f(t), tf(t))$
where $t \in [a, b]$. If we let $M = -y$ and $N = x$, we get:
$$
\int_{a}^{b} (-tf(t), f(t)).(f'(t), f(t) + tf'(t))dt = \iint_{\Sigma} 1 - (-1)dA
$$
$$
\int_{a}^{b} -tf(t)f'(t)+f^2(t)+tf(t)f'(t)dt = 2\iint_{\Sigma}dA
$$
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f^2(t)dt = 2\iint_{\Sigma}dA
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} f^2(t)dt = \iint_{\Sigma}dA
$$
$$
\therefore A = \frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b} f^2(t)dt
$$

Answer (score 1):

Parametric curves are just screaming out to be solved in the complex plane. Consider that

$$
z=f(t)+itf(t)\\
A=\frac{1}{2}\int\mathfrak{Im}\{z^* \dot z\}\ dt
$$
$$
z^*=f-itf\\
\dot z=\dot f+i(t\dot f+f)\\
z^*\dot z=(f-itf)[\dot f+i(t\dot f+f)]=f\dot f+(t\dot f+f)+i[f(t\dot f+f)-tf\dot f]\\
\mathfrak{Im}\{z^* \dot z\}=f^2
$$

Therefore

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b f^2(t)\,dt$$